# Cordova and Google Maps Javascript issue on iOS appstore

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, google-maps

I'm facing an issue on publishing a Cordova app on IOS store.

I'm using "Maps JavaScript API" that refers to google map browser view.

As I publish the app the tech support (first and second level) refuse it multiple times due to this problem "app’s location feature is not integrated with the built-in mapping functionality, which limits users to a third party Maps application. Revise your app to give users the option to launch the native Apple Maps application".

NOTE: I'm not talking about call the map application's device that is performed by:

```
if(device.platform == 'iOS')
  link = 'maps:q='+ item.address;
```

and produce this HTML:

```
<a href="maps:q=mylink.html">Click Here</a>
```

Can anyone suggest how to solve this issue? Documentation or examples are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html plugin so you can collect the devices coordinates, and before that send warning to user so he can allow you to use his position. You can find full example on the link.

Comment: Thanks for answer but our problem is not geolocation but the display of Google Maps on iOS in a 'div'.